# Binding datagrid column width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have two datagrids with one column each.
First:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FilterTextCol01" 
                       IsReadOnly="False" 
                       Width="{Binding ElementName=TextCol01, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Second:

```
<DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnContentLeft}"
                    local:DataGridUtil.Name="TextCol01"
                    x:Name="TextCol01"
                    Header="TextCol01"
                    SortMemberPath="TextCol01"
                    Binding="{Binding TextCol01}" 
                    Width="Auto" 
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Binding of the width of first column to the width of the second doesn't work.
If I'm doing it in code that way:

```
FilterTextCol01.Width = TextCol01.ActualWidth;
```

It works. 
Could anyone tell me why the first approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because `DataGrid` columns are abstract objects which do *not* appear in the logical or visual tree of your window. You cannot bind properties on them using `ElementName` (there will be no namescope which is needed for those bindings).

You can try using `Source` and [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) instead, e.g.

```xml
{Binding Source={x:Reference TextCol01}, Path=ActualWidth}
```

Comment: Can there be a TwoWay binding from read-only property ActualWidth?

Comment: @H.B. great. Thanks it works. I never would have guessed it. How long does one need to know such deep buried things?

Comment: @manton: Don't know, depends on when you stumble upon them, there are a lot of details in WPF which one may come across sooner or later, sometimes even after one or more years i suppose.

Comment: @manton: By the way, you might be interested in [methods to debug bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) and you should probably start to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) if they answer your question.

Comment: @H.B. But unexpectedly there is another problem with your solution: "Service provider is missing the INameResolver service" the part "x:Reference TextCol01" is underlined as error. Do you have any clue on what it might be?

Comment: @manton: You're using the designer i suppose? I would suggest you ignore the error as it is created by the designer [as far as i know](http://kenkumar.blogspot.com/2010/10/service-provider-is-missing.html).

Comment: @H.B. Thank you! You cannot imagine how frustrating this has been. Literally never seen x:Reference before!

Comment: @H.B. Is there any chance you know the `<Binding ... />` syntax of this answer for MultiBinding? I could use it for my question: [Bind DataGrid Column Width to Two Colums of Another DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762162/align-datagrid-column-to-two-colums-of-another-datagrid).

Comment: @Steven: Should simply be <Binding Source="{x:Reference ...}" Path="ActualWidth"/>

Answer (score 2):

As H.B. said this property isn't in logical or visual tree.

Also have a look at this approach based on a binding proxy.

**SourceCode**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductId1" Binding="{Binding Path=Result[0]}" Width="{Binding Data.Columns[0].Width, Source={StaticResource proxy}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProductId2" Binding="{Binding Path=Result[1]}" Width="{Binding Data.Columns[1].Width, Source={StaticResource proxy}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    //Override of Freezable
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }
    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}


public class Column : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public DataGridLength Width
    {
        get { return m_width; }
        set { m_width = value; OnPropertyChanged("Width"); }
    }
    DataGridLength m_width;
}
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46787502/5381620

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for something like this. I found a solution so i'm posting it in order to help some other person with the same issue.

**In my implementation i use a Custom DataTemplate for the Header of the DataGridTextColumn!!**

So assigning `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"` to the `TextBlock` used as DataGridColumnHeader i am able to set its `Width` to the `DataGridTextColumn` `ActualWidth`