# Bind DataGrid Column Width to Two Colums of Another DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, multibinding

**Question:** How do I bind `StatName.Width` to `Samp1.ActualWidth + Samp2.ActualWidth`?

[image: Current vs desired]

**Sub-questions:**

Why are my `WidthConverter` functions never executed (breakpoints never hit)?

What is the right `<Binding ...` syntax for the individual MultiBinding components?

**What I've tried:**

I think I need to assign the `DataGridTextColumn.Width` with `MultiBinding` and some type of converter.

I have tried putting together a solution from various examples online.  I can't seem to pull it all together.

**EDIT**

With using `<Binding ElementName="Samp1" Path="ActualWidth" />`

1. No build errors or warnings.
2. The `Convert` function is not hit
3. No relevant messages in Output

With using `<Binding Source="{x:Reference Samp1}" Path="ActualWidth" />`

1. Build error (that still allows execution): Specified cast is not valid. For `<MultiBinding>...</MultiBinding>`.
2. `Convert` is called three times when loading.  It is not called when resizing 
   column `Samp1`.
3. On each execution of `Convert:`

`System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='40' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=64879470); target property is 'Width' (type 'DataGridLength')`

---

**MultiBinding Attempt (xaml part)**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:WidthConverter x:Key="WidthConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>

    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Samp1" Binding="{Binding a}" Header="S1" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Samp2" Binding="{Binding b}" Header="S2" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Total" Binding="{Binding c}" Header="Tot" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <local:MyGenericRecord a="5000" b="2500" c="7500" />
        <local:MyGenericRecord a="1000" b="1500" c="2500" />
    </DataGrid>

    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StatName"  Binding="{Binding a}" Header="Stat">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Width>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="Samp1" Path="ActualWidth" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Samp2" Path="ActualWidth" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Width>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StatValue" Binding="{Binding b}" Header="Val" Width="{Binding ElementName=Total, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <local:MyGenericRecord a="Min" b="2500" />
        <local:MyGenericRecord a="Max" b="7500" />
        <local:MyGenericRecord a="Average" b="5000" />
    </DataGrid>

</StackPanel>
```

**MultiBinding Attempt (code part)**

```
public class WidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double totalWidth = 0;

        foreach (DataGridLength Width in values)
            totalWidth += Width.Value;

        return totalWidth;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `ActualWidth` isn't a `double`? I tried and change form `DataGridLength` to `double` and it worked.

Comment: @Bob I tried `foreach ( double Width in values ) totalWidth += Width;`.  The code compiled and ran, but the `StatName` column was still only as wide as  the word *Average*

Comment: @Bob I discovered that neither `WidthConverter` function is never called.  Do you know why?  Also, did my code sample execute correctly for you?

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your problem and I can now reproduce it. [I found some information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313586/binding-datagrid-column-width). I will try to find a way to solve it and let you know.

Comment: @Steven: The converter probably is not hit because the binding throws an error first. Always make sure to check the `Output` window for binding errors.

Comment: @H.B. With your help, I finally got the Binding and Converter working (see answer below).  However, the Visual Studio reports the error `Specified cast is not valid` on my MultiBinding statement.  Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @Steven: Probably because VS is stupid. Usually such errors are caused by the GUI designer, which i never even use.

Answer (score 1):

The code finally executes as expected with the following:

- `<Binding Source="{x:Reference Samp2}" Path="ActualWidth" />`
- `return new DataGridLength(totalWidth);`

The `Converter` gets called on load and when resizing `Samp1` or `Samp2`.  The column widths remain synchronized as expected.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StatName"  Binding="{Binding a}" Header="Stat">
   <DataGridTextColumn.Width >
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WidthConverter}">
           <Binding Source="{x:Reference Samp1}" Path="ActualWidth" />
           <Binding Source="{x:Reference Samp2}" Path="ActualWidth" />
       </MultiBinding>
   </DataGridTextColumn.Width>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The `Convert` function needed to return a `DataGridLength`, the data type of `DataGridTextColumn.Width`.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{

    double totalWidth = 0;

    foreach (double Width in values)
        totalWidth += Width;

    return new DataGridLength(totalWidth);
}
```

**Note:** The code executes as expected, regardless of the error `Specified cast is not valid.`

1. The Visual Studio designer underlines the entire tag `<MultiBinding ... </MultiBinding>` in cyan.
2. The *Error List* window reports the error "Specified cast is not valid."
3. While it is displayed as an error, Visual Studio will still build and execute the code.